# PDFJS: Get some unnecessary chunks with range request and make first page slow

Tags: pdf, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

Configuration:

- Web browser and its version:  Chrome 97.0.4692.99
- Operating system and its version:   MacOS 10.15.5
- PDF.js version:   2.12.313
- Is a browser extension:  no

1. I use the range request to render pdf
2. I get more chunks with this line of code `await this.pdfManager.requestRange(ex.begin, ex.end);`;
3. These chunks are unnecessary when rendering first page;
4. The program also seems to run fine when I comment this line of code, and I can get less chunks to make the first page faster;
5. So what does this part of the code do?
6. Is it possible not to execute it or not to use await?

```
// src/core/xref.js

async fetchAsync(ref, suppressEncryption) {
    try {
      return this.fetch(ref, suppressEncryption);
    } catch (ex) {
      if (!(ex instanceof MissingDataException)) {
        throw ex;
      }
      await this.pdfManager.requestRange(ex.begin, ex.end);
      return this.fetchAsync(ref, suppressEncryption);
    }
  }
```

I can get less chunks when I comment this line of code and the program also seems to run fine

[image]

If I do nothing，the range request in network like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v2.12.313, PDFJS will check that the last page can be sucessfully loaded during document initialization, to ensure that `numPages` is correct, and fallback to walking the entire /Pages-tree. [#14570](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/14570)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue and were able to get linearization to work as expected in PDFJS by forcing the PDF to be at version 1.6. The documents that are not working for us are at version 1.5.

We are using qpdf to create out PDF files. So we are able to set via the command line

```
--linearize --min-version=1.6
```